# The hex string got from jq can't be converted to decimal value

Tags: hex, decimal, jq

I define some hex strings in json file as follows:

*$ cat test.json*

```
{
    "device": {
        "value": "0x5",
        "mask": "0x4"
    }
}
```

And the below test.sh script is to read it from json file using jq and then convert the hex string to decimal integer, and then do AND operation.

$ cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

JSON_FILE="test.json"

VALUE=$(jq '.device.value' $JSON_FILE)
echo "Value: $VALUE"
MASK=$(jq '.device.mask' $JSON_FILE)
echo "Mask: $MASK"

ret_1=$(printf %u ${VALUE})
ret_2=$(printf %u ${MASK})
echo "value: ${ret_1}, mask: ${ret_2}"

RESULT=$((${ret_1} & ${ret_2}))
echo "Result: $RESULT"
```

However, we get the incorrect result because the step to convert hex string is failed, which is always 48 (0x30). Is there better solution? Thanks.

$ ./test.sh

```
Value: "0x5"
Mask: "0x4"
value: 48, mask: 48
Result: 48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jq's -r command-line option to stop jq from emitting the characters strings as JSON strings, i.e. with quotation marks.